# PHP preg_match_all riddle

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using PHP version 5.6 and I can't figure out why the regular expression won't match the second row correctly.

```
 $str = '<tr><td class="DH">Sale Date</td></tr><tr><td class="DD">10-MAR-15</td></tr><tr><td class="DD">18-APR-17</td></tr>';

 preg_match_all('/<tr>.*?class="D.*?<\/tr>/', $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches);

 preg_match_all('/<tr>.*?class="DH.*?<\/tr>/', $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches);

 preg_match_all('/<tr>.*?class="DD.*?<\/tr>/', $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

This code outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <tr><td class="DH">Sale Date</td></tr>
            [1] => <tr><td class="DD">10-MAR-15</td></tr>
            [2] => <tr><td class="DD">18-APR-17</td></tr>
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <tr><td class="DH">Sale Date</td></tr>
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <tr><td class="DH">Sale Date</td></tr><tr><td class="DD">10-MAR-15</td></tr>
            [1] => <tr><td class="DD">18-APR-17</td></tr>
        )

)
```

The regex essentially means match all shortest sequences between 
`<tr>` and `</tr>` that contain `class="D`.

Notice how the first regex matches all 3 rows individually correctly.

The second one does the same but wants the row to contain `class="DH` which it does correctly.

The third regex is supposed to match the other rows which contain `class="DD`. For some reason only the first result (corresponding to the second table row) wants to include the previous row.

Even if I add a space between `</tr>` and `<tr>` as in `</tr> <tr>`I'm getting the same result. However, if I insert a line break things work.

Can anyone explain what's going on and how to fix my code?

Comment: [Please don't try to parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser instead.](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/<tr>.*?class="DD.*?/
```

says "find `<tr>`, then match *everything* until you find `class="DD"`.  So it sees:

```
<tr><td class="DH">Sale Date</td></tr><tr><td class="DD">
```

and matches the first `<tr>`, then the `.*` matches `<td class="DH">Sale Date</td></tr><tr><td`, then it sees `class="DH"` which matches the next part.

When you add a line break, `.*` stops matching, so it makes it work.

Comment: I thought I had addressed that by using the lazy version `.*?` instead of the greedy `.*` but I guess the regex engine will not return the list of shortest possible overall results, but all results from any starting position. I think it makes sense now.